# SignalR npm package to use in React Native app

Tags: react-native, signalr

Which npm package do I need to use in a new React Native app?

I have a React app in which I use `@aspnet/signalr` but according to Microsoft documentation, the JavaScript client is `@microsoft/signalr`.

Which is the correct package to use in a React Native app that will connect to my hub running on ASP.NET Core which uses Azure SignalR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `@microsoft/signalr` package because this is the one that is still develop by microsoft and got updates. The `@aspent/signalr` is a deprecated package and is not longer maintained.